# How to insert IDs into Nodes when converting .csv to XML?

Tags: python

Hello I'm new to Python,

and I would like to convert a `.csv`file to `XML`. The desired output should look like, where I would like to have each individual ID within a Node: `<employee id="5">` and the variables corresponding to each individual beneath each other rather then on the same line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document>
  <employee id="1">
    <Name>Steve</Name>
    <City>Boston</City>
    <Age>33</Age>
  </employee>
  <employee id="2">
    <Name>Michael</Name>
    <City>Dallas</City>
    <Age>45</Age>
  </employee>
  <employee id="3">
    <Name>John</Name>
    <City>New York</City>
    <Age>89</Age>
  </employee>
  <employee id="4">
    <Name>Thomas</Name>
    <City>LA</City>
    <Age>62</Age>
  </employee>
  <employee id="5">
    <Name>Clint</Name>
    <City>Paris</City>
    <Age>30</Age>
  </employee>
</Document>
```

Given some data:

```
import pandas
ID = pandas.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5])
name = pandas.DataFrame(["Steve","Michael","John","Thomas","Clint"])
city = pandas.DataFrame(["Boston","Dallas","New York","LA","Paris"])
Age = pandas.DataFrame([45,33,33,20,50])
df = pandas.concat([ID, name,city,Age], axis=1)
df.columns = ['ID','name','city','Age']

df

    ID  name    city    Age

0   1   Steve   Boston  45
1   2   Michael Dallas  33
2   3   John    New York    33
3   4   Thomas  LA  20
4   5   Clint   Paris   50
```

And the conversion from `.csv` to `XML`:

```
import csv

csvFile = 'df.csv'
xmlFile = 'myData.xml'

csvData = csv.reader(open(csvFile))
xmlData = open(xmlFile, 'w')
xmlData.write('<?xml version="1.0"?>' + "\n")
# there must be only one top-level tag
xmlData.write('<Document>' + "\n")

rowNum = 0
for employee in csvData:
    if rowNum == 0:
       tags = employee 
       # replace spaces w/ underscores in tag names
       for i in range(len(tags)):
           tags[i] = tags[i].replace(' ', '_')
    else: 
       xmlData.write('<employee >' + "\n")
       for i in range(len(tags)):
           xmlData.write('    ' + '<' + tags[i] + '>' \
                        + employee [i] + '</' + tags[i] + '>' + "\n")
       xmlData.write('</employee >' + "\n")

    rowNum +=1

xmlData.write('</Document>' + "\n")
xmlData.close()
```

Output `XML` which looks a bit off as desired:

```
<<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Document>
<employee>
    <X>1</X>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Name>Steve</Name>
    <City>Boston</City>
    <Age>33</Age>
</employee>
<employee>
    <X>2</X>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Name>Michael</Name>
    <City>Dallas</City>
    <Age>45</Age>
</employee>
<employee>
    <X>3</X>
    <ID>3</ID>
    <Name>John</Name>
   <City>New York</City>
    <Age>89</Age>
</employee>
<employee>
    <X>4</X>
    <ID>4</ID>
    <Name>Thomas</Name>
    <City>LA</City>
    <Age>62</Age>
</employee>
 <employee>
    <X>5</X>
    <ID>5</ID>
    <Name>Clint</Name>
    <City>Paris</City>
    <Age>30</Age>
</employee>
</Document>
```

Comment: Duplicate of [pandas dataframe to xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31260151/python-pandas-dataframe-to-xml)

Comment: Hi @aluriak, thank you for that hint. However, the only duplicate are the topics aka XML and csv not the question, at least from my perspective

Comment: Hello, how about this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/18576067/6313992

Comment: Don't create XML files manually! Always use an XML parser: https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the delimiter of the csv file when creating the csv reader object (default is ',').

```
csvData = csv.reader(open(csvFile), delimiter=' ')
```

If this is not given, then the entries of tags are not in the format you want.

---

The else section in your for loop is not correct.
This should be the solution:

```
import csv

csvFile = 'df.csv'
xmlFile = 'myData.xml'

csvData = csv.reader(open(csvFile), delimiter=';')
xmlData = open(xmlFile, 'w')
xmlData.write('<?xml version="1.0"?>' + "\n")
# there must be only one top-level tag
xmlData.write('<Document>' + "\n")

rowNum = 0
for employee in csvData:
    if rowNum == 0:
       tags = employee 
       # replace spaces w/ underscores in tag names
       for i in range(len(tags)):
           tags[i] = tags[i].replace(' ', '_')
    else: 
       xmlData.write('<employee ' + tags[0] + '="' + employee[0] + '" >' + "\n")
       for i in range(1,len(tags)):
           xmlData.write('    ' + '<' + tags[i] + '>' \
                        + employee [i] + '</' + tags[i] + '>' + "\n")
       xmlData.write('</employee >' + "\n")

    rowNum +=1

xmlData.write('</Document>' + "\n")
xmlData.close()
```

Comment: Hi @MaBe, I edited the question. Thank you for that hint. However the main problem remains to create a node beginning with <employee id="1"> and so on

Answer (score 2):

Using an XML parser will be far easier. Here is your example using the [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#building-xml-documents) module. I assumed that you converted the dataframe to csv with `df.to_csv('df.csv')`

```
import csv
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

csvFile = 'df.csv'
csvData = csv.reader(open(csvFile))

root = ET.Element('Document')
next(csvData)  # skip header
for _, employee_id, name, city, age in csvData:
    employee_elem = ET.SubElement(root, "Employee")
    employee_elem.set('id', employee_id)  # set attribute

    # Child elements
    name_elem = ET.SubElement(employee_elem, "Name")
    name_elem.text = name
    city_elem = ET.SubElement(employee_elem, "City")
    city_elem.text = city
    age_elem = ET.SubElement(employee_elem, "Name")
    age_elem.text = age

ET.ElementTree(root).write('df.xml', encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
```

Comment: Hi @mavroprovato thank you for your time! May I ask you one final question. How would you save the `XML` with appropriate `UTF-8` encoding, as in my example above, by adding 
`xmlFile = 'myData.xml'` `xmlData.close()` and `xmlData.write(?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?\>')`
 at the end of the document or beginning?

Comment: See my updated answer. The documentation for the `write` method is here: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write