# BigQuery (Dataframe) to XML

Tags: python, xml, dataframe, google-bigquery

I am trying to do an XML export of a BigQuery query via python using a code I found at this link: [Python Pandas Dataframe to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31260151/python-pandas-dataframe-to-xml) but I have the error below, could you help me solve this?

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from google.cloud import bigquery

script_path = "C:\\Keys\\key.json"
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = script_path

client = bigquery.Client(project='project_id')
query_job = client.query("SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM dataset.table ")
df_bq = query_job.to_dataframe()

def to_xml(df, filename=None, mode='w'):
    def row_to_xml(row):
        xml = ['<item>']
        for i, col_name in enumerate(row.index):
            xml.append('  <field name="{0}">{1}</field>'.format(col_name, row.iloc[i]))
        xml.append('</item>')
        return '\n'.join(xml)
    res = '\n'.join(df.apply(row_to_xml, axis=1))

    if filename is None:
        return res
    with open(filename, mode) as f:
        f.write(res)

pd.DataFrame.to_xml = to_xml

df.to_xml('test.xml')
```

> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 df.to_xml('table.xml')
>
> NameError: name 'df' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no variable `df` assigned to anything, before line `df.to_xml('test.xml')`. You are essentially calling a method from a non-existent variable. Therefore, `NameError` prompts.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I knew it was simple, I'm getting better at Python and asking questions around here help me evolve. If possible, I would like you to consider this in your assessment as I can't ask any more questions on stackoverflow right now.

Answer (score 0):

I made some code changes and managed to generate the file from a bigquery select

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from google.cloud import bigquery

script_path = "C:\\Keys\\key.json"
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = script_path

client = bigquery.Client(project='project_id')
query_job = client.query("SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM dataset.table ")
df = query_job.to_dataframe()

def to_xml(df, filename=None, mode='w'):
    def row_to_xml(row):
        xml = ['<item>']
        for i, col_name in enumerate(row.index):
            xml.append('  <field name="{0}">{1}</field>'.format(col_name, row.iloc[i]))
        xml.append('</item>')
        return '\n'.join(xml)
    res = '\n'.join(df.apply(row_to_xml, axis=1))

    if filename is None:
        return res
    with open(filename, mode, encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write(res)

pd.DataFrame.to_xml = to_xml

df.to_xml('test.xml')
```