# Python 2.7 / Pandas: writing new string from each row in dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

In Pandas, I have a dataframe, written from a csv. My end goal is to generate an XML schema from that CSV, because each of the items in the CSV correspond to a schema variable. The only solution (that I could think of) would be to read each item from that dataframe so that it generates a text file, with each value in the dataframe surrounded by a string.

```
TableName  Variable      Interpretation   Col4   Col5
CRASH      CRASH_ID      integer          1     
CRASH      SER_NO        range            0
CRASH      SER_NO        code             99999
CRASH      CRASH_MO_NO   code             1      January
CRASH      CRASH_MO_NO   code             2      February
```

Which would generate a text file that results in something along the lines of (using the first row as an example):

```
<table = "CRASH">
<name = "CRASH_ID">
<type = "integer">
<value = "1">
```

Where `<table = >, <name = >`, are all strings. They don't have to be formatted that way specifically (although that would be nice)-- I just need a faster way to generate this schema than typing it all out by hand from a CSV file.

It seems like the best way to do that would be to read through each row and generate a string while writing it to the output file. I've looked at the .iterrows() method, but that doesn't let me concatenate strings and tuples. I've also [looked](http://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_iterate_over_rows_of_multiple_columns.html) at some [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837722/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-loop-through-dataframes-with-pandas) from [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe) users, but their focus seems to be more on calculating things within dataframes, or changing the data itself, rather than generating a string from each row.

My current code is below. I understand that pandas is based off Numpy arrays, and that running "for i in df" loops is not an efficient method, but I am not really sure where to start.

EDIT: Some of the rows might need to loop through to display a certain way. For instance, the schema has multiple value codes that have strings attached:

```
<values>
<value code = "01">January</value>
<value code = "02">February</value>
<value code = "03">March</value>
</values>
```

I am thinking maybe I could group the values by "interpretation"? And then, if they have the "code" interpretation, I could do some kind of iteration through the group so that it displayed all the codes.

Here is my current code, for reference. I have updated it to reflect Randy's excellent suggestion below. I have also edited the above post to reflect some updated concerns.

```
import pandas as pd

text_file = open(r'oregon_output.txt', 'w')

df = pd.read_csv(r'oregon_2013_var_list.csv')

#selects only CRASH variables
crash = df['Col1'] == 'CRASH'
df_crash = df[crash]

#value which will be populated with code values from codebook
code_fill = " " 

#replaces NaN values in dataframe wih code_fill
df_crash.fillna(code_fill, inplace = True)

for row_id, row in df.iterrows():
    print '<variable>'
    for k, v in row.iterkv():
        if v is not None:
            print '<{} = "{}">'.format(k, v)
    print '</variable>'
    print
```

Comment: duplicate of this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18574108/how-do-convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-xml

Comment: Sort of. However, my schema has slightly different needs-- I added a little more on to my question to expand upon it. Also, I do not fully understand the answers that were given to that question, and I do not want to necro-bump that thread since it was posted two years ago...Thank you for your response, though, it was still helpful!

Answer (score 0):

It probably does make sense to just iterate through it and spit out individual rows:

```
for row_id, row in df.iterrows():
    for k, v in row.iterkv():
        if v is not None:
            print '<{} = "{}">'.format(k, v)
    print
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, I am not entirely sure I understand the .iterkv() method, and because it seems like it uses arguments that you arbitrarily chose (i.e. k,v), I can't google it. Could you expand a little more on what that method is, and why you chose it?

Comment: k, v stands for each key value pair.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`to_dict()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) method you may want to consider in this case:

```
In [178]:
df.columns = ['table','name','type','value']
[["<%s='%s'>"%(k,v) for k,v in D.items()] for D in df.to_dict('records')]

Out[178]:
[["<table='CRASH'>", "<type='integer'>", "<name='CRASH_ID'>", "<value='1.0'>"],
 ["<table='CRASH'>", "<type='range'>", "<name='SER_NO'>", "<value='0.0'>"],
 ["<table='CRASH'>", "<type='code'>", "<name='SER_NO'>", "<value='99999.0'>"],
 ["<table='CRASH'>", "<type='string'>", "<name='CRASH_DT'>", "<value='nan'>"]]
```