# Simple CSV to XML Conversion - Python

Tags: python, xml, csv, parsing

I am looking for a way to automate the conversion of CSV to XML.

Here is an example of a CSV file, containing a list of movies:

[image: Movies Csv]

Here is the file in XML format:

```
<collection shelf="New Arrivals">
<movietitle="Enemy Behind">
   <type>War, Thriller</type>
   <format>DVD</format>
   <year>2003</year>
   <rating>PG</rating>
   <stars>10</stars>
   <description>Talk about a US-Japan war</description>
</movie>
<movietitle="Transformers">
   <type>Anime, Science Fiction</type>
   <format>DVD</format>
   <year>1989</year>
   <rating>R</rating>
   <stars>8</stars>
   <description>A schientific fiction</description>
</movie>
<movietitle="Trigun">
   <type>Anime, Action</type>
   <format>DVD</format>
   <episodes>4</episodes>
   <rating>PG</rating>
   <stars>10</stars>
   <description>Vash the Stampede!</description>
</movie>
<movietitle="Ishtar">
   <type>Comedy</type>
   <format>VHS</format>
   <rating>PG</rating>
   <stars>2</stars>
   <description>Viewable boredom</description>
</movie>
</collection>
```

I've tried a few examples where I am able to read the csv and XML format using Python using DOM and SAX but yet am to find a simple example of the conversion. So far I have:

```
import csv              
f = open('movies2.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)   

def convert_row(row):
   return """<movietitle="%s">
   <type>%s</type>
   <format>%s</format>
   <year>%s</year>
   <rating>%s</rating>
   <stars>%s</stars>
   <description>%s</description>
</movie>""" % (
   row.Title, row.Type, row.Format, row.Year, row.Rating, row.Stars, row.Description)

print ('\n'.join(csv_f.apply(convert_row, axis=1)))
```

But I get the error:

```
 File "moviesxml.py", line 16, in module
   print ('\n'.join(csv_f.apply(convert_row, axis=1)))
AttributeError: '_csv.reader' object has no attribute 'apply'
```

I am pretty new to Python, so any help would be much appreciated!

I am using Python 3.5.2.

Thanks!

Lisa

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the Python code you have tried. Does it work?

Comment: hi, for some reason my code for DOM and SAX corrupted and I forgot where I found the sample code. I've included the import csv method

Comment: Future readers, avoid most answers on this post. See [What''s so bad about building XML with string concatenation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3034611/1422451). XML is not a text file to be built with string formatting. Use appropriate DOM libraries like Python's etree or lxml.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A possible solution is to first load the csv into Pandas and then convert it row by row into XML, as so:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('untitled.txt', sep='|')
```

With the sample data (assuming separator and so on) loaded as:

```
          Title                   Type Format  Year Rating  Stars  \
0  Enemy Behind           War,Thriller    DVD  2003     PG     10   
1  Transformers  Anime,Science Fiction    DVD  1989      R      9   

             Description  
0          Talk about...  
1  A Schientific fiction
```

And then converting to xml with a custom function:

```
def convert_row(row):
    return """<movietitle="%s">
    <type>%s</type>
    <format>%s</format>
    <year>%s</year>
    <rating>%s</rating>
    <stars>%s</stars>
    <description>%s</description>
</movie>""" % (
    row.Title, row.Type, row.Format, row.Year, row.Rating, row.Stars, row.Description)

print '\n'.join(df.apply(convert_row, axis=1))
```

This way you get a string containing the xml:

```
<movietitle="Enemy Behind">
    <type>War,Thriller</type>
    <format>DVD</format>
    <year>2003</year>
    <rating>PG</rating>
    <stars>10</stars>
    <description>Talk about...</description>
</movie>
<movietitle="Transformers">
    <type>Anime,Science Fiction</type>
    <format>DVD</format>
    <year>1989</year>
    <rating>R</rating>
    <stars>9</stars>
    <description>A Schientific fiction</description>
</movie>
```

that you can dump in to a file or whatever.

Inspired by [this great answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18576067/3402367)

---

Edit: Using the loading method you posted (or a version that actually loads the data to a variable):

```
import csv              
f = open('movies2.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)   
data = []

for row in csv_f: 
   data.append(row)
f.close()

print data[1:]
```

We get:

```
[['Enemy Behind', 'War', 'Thriller', 'DVD', '2003', 'PG', '10', 'Talk about...'], ['Transformers', 'Anime', 'Science Fiction', 'DVD', '1989', 'R', '9', 'A Schientific fiction']]
```

And we can convert to XML with minor modifications:

```
def convert_row(row):
    return """<movietitle="%s">
    <type>%s</type>
    <format>%s</format>
    <year>%s</year>
    <rating>%s</rating>
    <stars>%s</stars>
    <description>%s</description>
</movie>""" % (row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6])

print '\n'.join([convert_row(row) for row in data[1:]])
```

Getting identical results:

```
<movietitle="Enemy Behind">
    <type>War</type>
    <format>Thriller</format>
    <year>DVD</year>
    <rating>2003</rating>
    <stars>PG</stars>
    <description>10</description>
</movie>
<movietitle="Transformers">
    <type>Anime</type>
    <format>Science Fiction</format>
    <year>DVD</year>
    <rating>1989</rating>
    <stars>R</stars>
    <description>9</description>
</movie>
```

Comment: Why Pandas? The Python Standard Library contains a CSV module.

Comment: @LutzHorn No particular reason. OP didn't specify what method was used to load the data at first, and Pandas is a great library that I'm used to.

Comment: hi thanks for your post. I tried to install panda using 'sudo pip install pandas' but I get the message 'ImportError: no module named 'pandas''

Comment: Also (sorry i'm a real newbie) how to I save this into as an XML file - movies.xml

Comment: @LMarfell I edited my answer to account for your loading method. No need for pandas (although I recommend it if you often manipulated csv files).

Comment: @RobertoIzquierdo brilliant! Thanks so much. How do I then write this data to an .xml file?

Comment: @LMarfell `with open('out.xml', 'w') as f: f.write('\n'.join(df.apply(convert_row, axis=1)))`, don't forget to add the part with `<collection shelf="New Arrivals">` and so on, it's just string concatenation ;)

Comment: @RobertoIzquierdo Many thanks. It said df not defined, so I changed df for csv_f, but it says 'AttributeError: '_csv.reader' object has no attribute 'apply'', without apply it says '_csv.reader' object is not callable'

Comment: @RobertoIzquierdo yes i am using import csv, rather than panda

Comment: @LMarfell My bad, it should be something like with `with open('out.xml', 'w') as f: f.write('\n'.join([convert_row(row) for row in data]))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130220/discussion-between-l-marfell-and-roberto-izquierdo).

Answer (score 3):

I tried to generalize [robertoia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3402367/robertoia)'s function convert_row for any header instead of writing it by hand.

```
import csv  
import pandas as pd
            
f = open('movies2.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)   
data = []

for row in csv_f: 
   data.append(row)
f.close()

df = pd.read_csv('movies2.csv')
header= list(df.columns)

def convert_row(row):
     str_row = """<%s>%s</%s> \n"""*(len(header)-1)
     str_row = """<%s>%s""" +"\n"+ str_row + """</%s>"""
     var_values = [list_of_elments[k] for k in range(1,len(header)) for list_of_elments in [header,row,header]]
     var_values = [header[0],row[0]]+var_values+[header[0]]
     var_values =tuple(var_values)
     return str_row % var_values

text ="""<collection shelf="New Arrivals">"""+"\n"+'\n'.join([convert_row(row) for row in data[1:]])+"\n" +"</collection >"
print(text)
with open('output.xml', 'w') as myfile: 
  myfile.write(text)
```

Of course with pandas now, it is simpler to just use
`to_xml()` :

```
df= pd.read_csv('movies2.csv')
with open('outputf.xml', 'w') as myfile: 
  myfile.write(df.to_xml())
```

Answer (score 1):

I found an easier way to insert variables into a string or block of text:

```
'''Twas brillig and the slithy {what}
Did gyre and gimble in the {where}
All {how} were the borogoves
And the {who} outgrabe.'''.format(what='toves',
                                  where='wabe',
                                  how='mimsy',
                                  who='momeraths')
```

Alternatively:

```
'''Twas brillig and the slithy {0}
Did gyre and gimble in the {1}
All {2} were the borogoves
And the {3} outgrabe.'''.format('toves',
                                'wabe',
                                'mimsy',
                                'momeraths')
```

(substitute name of incoming data variable for `'toves', 'wabe', 'mimsy',` and `'momeraths'`)

Answer (score 0):

Can be done without any libraries too simple script as below assumes the CSV file as cvs_to_xml_data.csv with single column value.

```
"""This script is to create xmlfile.txt file from a given csv_to_xml_data.csv file"""
row_list = []
with open('csv_to_xml_data.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    row_list = csvfile.read().splitlines()

with open('xmlfile.txt', 'w') as txtfile:
    for row in row_list:
        txtfile.write(f"""<Student>
    <studentclass>8thstd</studentclass>
    <studentsubject>math</<studentsubject>
    <stuItem>{row}<stuItem>
    <stuItemSting>I am {row} and I like to be {row} because I am {row} 
</stuItemSting>
</Student>""")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would modify, simplify a bit xml ouput structure (if possible), and then you will be able to use this simple script. Just instead of movietitle="Piti-piti pa" you would have:

```
<movie>
<title>Piti-piti Pa</title>
...
</movie>
```

Variations of the prompt:

```
echo -e 'id,name,surname\n1,"Jane","Flame"\n2,"John","Ash"' | ./csv2xml.py > outputfile.xml
echo -e 'id,name,surname\n1,"Jane","Flame"\n2,"John","Ash"' > inputfile.csv
./csv2xml.py < inputfile.csv > outputfile.xml
```

Example of outputfile.xml:

```
<document>
 <record>
  <id>1</id>
  <name>Jane</name>
  <surname>Flame</surname>
 </record>
 <record>
  <id>2</id>
  <name>John</name>
  <surname>Ash</surname>
 </record>
</document>
```

The program itself:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import csv
import fileinput

csv.register_dialect('custom',
                     delimiter=',',
                     doublequote=True,
                     escapechar=None,
                     quotechar='"',
                     quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL,
                     skipinitialspace=False)
first_line=True
data = csv.reader(fileinput.input(), dialect='custom')
print("<document>")
for record in data:
    if first_line==True:
        first_line=False
        name_of_fields=record
    else:
        print(" <record>")
        for i, field in enumerate(record):
            print("  <" + name_of_fields[i] + ">" + field + "</" + name_of_fields[i] + ">" )
        print(" </record>")
print("</document>")
```