# How to do a string replace and a re.sub altogether in a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to convert a file from csv to xml by doing some replaces. I don't know if this is the best way but sounded a simpler and easy way to do it, since the files are quite simple.
The thing is, the last replace I have to do is a regex and I don't know how to append that to all the replaces that come before.

```
import re
text = open("input.csv", "r")
x = open("output.xml","w")
for line in text:
    x.write(line.replace("QWERT=", "<Doc3045 QWERT=\"") \
    .replace(",Date=", "\" Date=\"") \
    .replace("ABCDE,Tp,CD", "") \
    .replace("S,1,", "<Cli Tp=\"1\" ABCDE=\"S\" Cd=\"") \
    .replace(",", "\">"))
#regex replace should go here
text.close()
x.close()
```

I already have the regex replace ready:

```
line = re.sub(r'(\d$)', r'\1"/>', line)
```

but I couldn't find a way to apply it inside the `for` within the input file or even to open the output file and applying the regex.

Comment: Why don't you just make apply the replaces for `line` to line itself, then apply the sub function to it, and THEN use `x.write(line)`?

Comment: Not sure if a duplicate (because your question is actually about combining replace and sub) but this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41059264/simple-csv-to-xml-conversion-python