# Converting pandas dataframe to XML

Tags: python, xml, pandas

I know this question has been asked before and my last was put on hold, so now I'm specifying it detailed.
I have a CSV file of population information, I read it to pandas and now have to transform it to XML, for example like this
     `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <populationdata>
     <municipality>
     <name>
       Akaa
     </name>
     <year>
       2014
     </year>
     <total>
       17052
      ......`

This is the reading part of my code:
`import pandas as pd
pop = pd.read_csv(r'''directory\population.csv''', delimiter=";")`

Tried doing it like in mentioned before in the link here with function and cycle: [How do convert a pandas/dataframe to XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18574108/how-do-convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-xml). Haven't succeeded, any other recommendations maybe?

This is an example of my dataframe:
      `Alahärmä  2014      0   0.1   0.2
0      Alajärvi  2014  10171  5102  5069
1      Alastaro  2014      0     0     0
2     Alavieska  2014   2687  1400  1287
3        Alavus  2014  12103  6102  6001
4  Anjalankoski  2014      0     0     0`

Fairly new to python, so any help is apreciated.

Comment: Could you show us a head() of your dataframe

Comment: this is what it showed:                                                                                         `Alahärmä  2014      0   0.1   0.2
0      Alajärvi  2014  10171  5102  5069
1      Alastaro  2014      0     0     0
2     Alavieska  2014   2687  1400  1287
3        Alavus  2014  12103  6102  6001
4  Anjalankoski  2014      0     0     0`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do convert a pandas/dataframe to XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18574108/how-do-convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question you have linked to actually has a great answer to your question but I guess you’re having difficulty transposing your data into that solution so Ive done it below for you.

Ok your level of detail is a bit sketchy. If your specific situation differs slightly then you'll need to tweak my answer but heres something that works for me:

First off assuming you have a text file as follows :

```
0       Alahärmä  2014      0   0.1   0.2
1      Alajärvi  2014  10171  5102  5069
2      Alastaro  2014      0     0     0
3     Alavieska  2014   2687  1400  1287
4        Alavus  2014  12103  6102  6001
5  Anjalankoski  2014      0     0     0
```

Moving on to creating the python script, we first import that text file using the following line:

```
pop = pd.read_csv(r'directory\population.csv', delimiter=r"\s+", names=['cityname', 'year', 'total', 'male', 'females'])
```

This brings in the text file as a dataframe and gives the new dataframe the correct column headers.

Then taking the data from the question you linked to, we add the following to our python script:

```
def func(row):
    xml = ['<item>']
    for field in row.index:
        xml.append('  <field name="{0}">{1}</field>'.format(field, row[field]))
    xml.append('</item>')
    return '\n'.join(xml)

print('\n'.join(pop.apply(func, axis=1)))
```

Now we put it all together and we get the below:

```
import pandas as pd
pop = pd.read_csv(r'directory\population.csv', delimiter=r"\s+", names=['cityname', 'year', 'total', 'male', 'females'])

def func(row):
    xml = ['<item>']
    for field in row.index:
        xml.append('  <field name="{0}">{1}</field>'.format(field, row[field]))
    xml.append('</item>')
    return '\n'.join(xml)

print('\n'.join(pop.apply(func, axis=1)))
```

When we run the above file we get the following output:

```
<item>
  <field name="cityname">Alahärmä</field>
  <field name="year">2014</field>
  <field name="total">0</field>
  <field name="male">0.1</field>
  <field name="females">0.2</field>
</item>
<item>
  <field name="cityname">Alajärvi</field>
  <field name="year">2014</field>
  <field name="total">10171</field>
  <field name="male">5102.0</field>
  <field name="females">5069.0</field>
</item>
<item>
  <field name="cityname">Alastaro</field>
  <field name="year">2014</field>
  <field name="total">0</field>
  <field name="male">0.0</field>
  <field name="females">0.0</field>
</item>
<item>
  <field name="cityname">Alavieska</field>
  <field name="year">2014</field>
  <field name="total">2687</field>
  <field name="male">1400.0</field>
  <field name="females">1287.0</field>
</item>
<item>
  <field name="cityname">Alavus</field>
  <field name="year">2014</field>
  <field name="total">12103</field>
  <field name="male">6102.0</field>
  <field name="females">6001.0</field>
</item>
<item>
  <field name="cityname">Anjalankoski</field>
  <field name="year">2014</field>
  <field name="total">0</field>
  <field name="male">0.0</field>
  <field name="females">0.0</field>
</item>
```

Comment: You are gold! I was getting few errors, because of brackets or ' in wrong place. Thanks!

Comment: Last question: how about would I be able to save this output to xml file?

Comment: If it still helps you or someone: import lxml.etree as ET  
parser = ET.XMLParser(recover=True)
tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(xml, parser=parser))   tree.write(filelocation)