# Is there a generic Python script / Module which can convert XSD to XML?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

I am relatively new to Python and wanted to convert .csv files to XML. Is there a Python module / script which can help in creating this generic?

Though I have already to created custom script which process csv file to and convert them to XML, but was wondering if it can be created to a generic script?

I expect the process to work as "**python_script.py Input_XSD_file.xsd Input_CSV_File.csv**"

and it creates relevant XML files.

Comment: Do you want to know how to modify your script to accept arguments, or how to change your code so that it works with any xsd / csv file?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: I want to create a generic Python script which accepts an XSD and creates a corresponding XML file, the data in the XML file can be loaded via a csv file or a database.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the **pandas** module (which is an important module to know if you are getting into python for data analysis). You create a pandas dataframe from a csv as follows:

```
    import pandas as pd
    my_df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

Then you can convert your dataframe into XML using the answer to this question : [How do convert a pandas/dataframe to XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18574108/how-do-convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-xml)

Comment: Thanks for the update @Orysza, but I was looking for a way to make it a generic process where the XML is created from an XSD passed as a **parameter**. But as per the link you helped with is creating an _hard-coded_ XML structure.