# Error while reading data from table and converting to xml using pandas

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, pandas

I am reading a data from table and want to converting to XML file.

I am successfully read data from table and store in dataframe but not able to convert to xml.

**Reading the data from table to dataframe**

```
       import cx_Oracle
            import pandas as pd
            from datetime import date
            import time

             CONN_INFO = {
                    'host': 'xxxxxx',
                    'port': 1521,
                    'user': 'xxxxx',
                    'psw': 'xxxxx',
                    'service': 'xxxxx',
                }

                CONN_STR = '{user}/{psw}@{host}:{port}/{service}'.format(**CONN_INFO)

                connection=cx_Oracle.connect(CONN_STR)
                cursor=connection.cursor()

    cursor.execute("""with M0 as (select 
         os.order_id order_id
         , MIN(os.EFFECTIVE_TIMESTAMP) as M0_DT
    FROM
        V_F_OR_STATUS_HISTORY    os 
    WHERE
         os.status_type IN ('0170','0112','2364','2363')
         AND trunc(os.EFFECTIVE_TIMESTAMP)  >= trunc(sysdate)-5
    GROUP BY
         os.order_id 
    """)
 data=cursor.fetchall()
```

**Output**

```
 [('GLAXO.4501201394', datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 29, 0, 0)),
 ('GLAXO.SG70X4501162986-THNEO', datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 26, 0, 0)),
 ('GLAXO.8000334269', datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 5, 0, 0)),
 ('GLAXO.20190828168057', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 6, 0, 0)),
 ('GLAXO.PH22X4501136042-THNEO', datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 13, 0, 0)),
 ('GLAXO.4501205247', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 3, 0, 0)),
 ('GLAXO.256286313', datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 21, 0, 0)),
 ('GLAXO.4501205964', datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 7, 0, 0))]
```

**Coverting to XML**

I tried the below refernce avialable from stackoverlow its not converting to xml

```
 root = etree.Element('data');

    for i,row in data.iterrows():
        item = etree.SubElement(root, 'item', attrib=row.to_dict());

  etree.dump(root);

    xml.etree.ElementTree.parse('xml_file.xml');
```

How to fix this. Any help is appreciated

Comment: What means "is not working" (edit the question)?

Comment: @MichaelButscher, its not converting to xml

Comment: Could you post the SO reference that you speak of?

Comment: @AnoopRDesai :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18574108/how-do-convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-xml

Comment: So what is the error? How can we reproduce it? Please take some time to provide a [mcve].

Comment: What is the output of the last code sample (edit question to show it)?

Comment: The "Reading the data from table to dataframe" code (badly formatted as it is) apparently works for you. So why is it in the question? And we don't have access to your database so we cannot run that code anyway.