# Pandas DataFrame to XML with added data

Tags: python, xml, pandas, dataframe

I am having a hard time generating a `.xml` file from a Pandas DataFrame. I am using this solution ([How do convert a pandas/dataframe to XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18574108/how-do-convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-xml)) (sorry, for some reason stack wont let me link a word to the site), but am trying to add an additional field. The original solution works if I do not include the `shape` parameters, but I do need to add the values into the `.xml` file. I am not sure why I cannot call the function with the arguments. In addition to calling the function, I am having a hard time writing as an xml. I have searched through a few other stack questions and have found that this code chunk works, but when I open the `.xml` file I get only four numbers (30, 1, 67, 44) which are the. Though if I open it in pycharm I get the "desired" view.

```
file_handle = open("output.xml", "w")
Q.writexml(file_handle)
file_handle.close()
```

Code:

```
print(image_x.shape)
output: (185, 186, 3)

width = image_x.shape[0]
height = image_x.shape[1]
depth = image_x.shape[2]

def func(row, width, height, depth):
    xml = ['<item>']
    shape = [f'<width>{width}</width>\n<height>{height}</height>\n<depth>{depth}</depth>']
    for field in row.index:
        xml.append('  <{0}>{1}</{0}>'.format(field, row[field]))
    xml.append('</item>')
    xml.append(shape)
    return '\n'.join(xml)

xml_file = func(df, width, height, depth)
```

df:

```
   xmin  ymin  xmax  ymax
0    30     1    67    44
1    39   136    73   176
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PyCharmEnvironments\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3080, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4554, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4562, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PycharmProjects/Augmentation/random_shit.py", line 100, in <module>
    Q = func(df, width, height, depth)
  File "D:/PycharmProjects/Augmentation/random_shit.py", line 95, in func
    xml.append('  <{0}>{1}</{0}>'.format(field, row[field]))
  File "D:\PyCharmEnvironments\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3024, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "D:\PyCharmEnvironments\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3082, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 0
```

**Desired Output:**

```
<annotations>
  <size>
    <width>185</width>
    <height>186</height>
    <depth>3</depth>
  </size>
  <item>
    <xmin>30</xmin>
    <ymin>1</ymin>
    <xmax>67</xmax>
    <ymax>44</ymax>
  </item>
  <item>
    <xmin>39</xmin>
    <ymin>136</ymin>
    <xmax>73</xmax>
    <ymax>176</ymax>
  </item>
</annotations>
```

Comment: it looks like you are providing the full df to your function. but from your link, it's meant to be applied to each row in the df.

Comment: @KJDII Okay I think I understand. That is why the have `'\n'.join(df.apply(func, axis=1)`? Would I need to create a function within a function?

Comment: you might be able to do exactly ```'\n'.join(df.apply(func, axis=1)```  Maybe: ```xml_file = '\n'.join(df.apply(func, axis=1) ```

Comment: I can do the `'\n'.join(df.apply(func, axis=1)` and set it to a variable such as what you have. But that is only if I do not include the `shape` stuff. Also, the output `.xml` does not save correctly (as mentioned in my questions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single-liner func:

```
def func(df, width, height, depth):
    return '<annotations>\n'+f'<width>{width}</width>\n<height>{height}</height>\n<depth>{depth}</depth>\n'+df.apply(lambda row:f'<item>\n<xmin>{row.xmin}</xmin>\n<ymin>{row.ymin}</ymin>\n<xmax>{row.xmax}</xmax>\n<ymax>{row.ymax}</ymax>\n</item>\n',axis=1).str.cat()+'\n</annotations>'
```

Concatenating strings with `+` and using a map-reduce approach to the dataframe with apply and cat. Apply will build each dataframe row and transform it to a string equivalent to the `<item>` tag, and str.cat() will concatenate each line (also renamed the input parameter row to df)

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you please explain what the `lambda` is doing? I have come across this before, but do not understand the documentation.

Comment: in general terms, `lambda` is the way you can have functions in place, instead of referencing a named function that you have declared elsewhere with `def`

Answer (score 0):

Because XML is not exactly a text file, avoid the common pet peeve of [building XML with string concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3034611/1422451). So avoid solutions in that linked post which may not properly handle encoding in your data. Recall [XML](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) stands for E**x**tensible **M**arkup **L**anguage that defines a set of rules for encoding documents.

Therefore, consider using a compliant DOM library like Python's built-in `etree` or feature-rich, third-party `lxml`:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et 
# import lxml.etree as et

root = et.Element("annotations")

size = et.SubElement(root, "size")
et.SubElement(size, "width").text = str(image.shape[0])
et.SubElement(size, "length").text = str(image.shape[1])
et.SubElement(size, "depth").text = str(image.shape[2])

data = image.to_dict(orient='records')

for d in data:
   item = et.SubElement(root, "item")

   for k, v in d.items():
      et.SubElement(item, k).text = str(v)

with open("output.xml", "wb") as f:
   f.write(et.tostring(root, encoding="utf8"))
```

To pretty print output with line breaks and indentation, use [toprettyxml](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.dom.minidom.html#xml.dom.minidom.Node.toprettyxml) in built-in `minidom`. Note: `lxml.etree` has a `pretty_print` argument in its `tostring` call.

```py
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString

# ...same code as above except write output

dom = parseString(et.tostring().decode("utf-8"))

with open("output.xml", "wb") as f:
   f.write(dom.toprettyxml(encoding="utf8"))
```