# Conversion of pandas dataframe into string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to include a table in an xml file. For this, I need to convert the panda's data frame into a string.

I tried applying the following code

```
string = df.to_string
```

but when I tried, I am getting the following error:

"TypeError: cannot serialize <bound method DataFrame.to_string of"

any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `df.to_string()`. Note the parentheses.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html as @JustinEzequiel said above add the brackets

Comment: yes, with brackets, the conversion to xml works. Thanks you for help.

Comment: You can find the answer here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18574108/how-do-convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-xml

Answer (score 0):

As Paul and Justin mentioned in the comments, you're just missing a parentheses.

`df.to_string()`

should do the trick.